# iis invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to add another table in here "dbo.ARTICLE_INCARNATION.article_incarnation_id", but I keep getting the error:

> iis invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

I have tried what i know to fix it but no progress.

```
SELECT 
'Summary',SUM( OBJ#CAB.object_qty) AS 'Sum est, OBW exist',
    AIN.article_incarnation_long_no AS 'Article no',
    AIN.article_incarnation_name AS 'Article name',

    SUM( OBJ#CAB.object_qty) AS 'Sum est, OBW exist',
    (SELECT 
  isnull(sum(POI.purchase_order_item_qty_po),0)
 FROM 
   [dbo].[PURCHASE_ORDER_ITEM] POI 
WHERE  
  POI.article_incarnation_id = AIN.article_incarnation_id
  AND POI.purchase_order_id IS NOT NULL), 
    (SELECT sum(isnull(stock_object_qty_qty,0)) FROM [dbo].[STOCK_OBJECT_QTY] S  WHERE S.article_incarnation_id = OBJ#CAB.article_incarnation_id) AS 'Total on stock' 
    /*AS 'Manko'
    AS 'PO',
    AS 'Not deliverd PO'*/
--skalmed

FROM

    OBJECT OBJ#CAB 
    JOIN OBJECT_TYPE OTY#CAB ON OTY#CAB.object_type_id = OBJ#CAB.object_type_id  
    AND OTY#CAB.object_type_no = 'CABLE'
    JOIN [dbo].[ARTICLE_INCARNATION] AIN ON OBJ#CAB.article_incarnation_id = AIN.article_incarnation_id
    AND AIN.article_unit_no = 'M'
    JOIN OBJECT_WORK OBW#CAB ON OBW#CAB.object_id = OBJ#CAB.object_id
    AND OBW#CAB.work_type_no IN ('EPU', 'EPA', 'IPA', 'XEPU', 'LI5', 'LE5')
    AND OBW#CAB.object_work_installed_qty IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    AIN.article_incarnation_long_no,
    AIN.article_incarnation_name,
    ARTICLE_INCARNATION.article_incarnation_id,
    OBJ#CAB.article_incarnation_id
```

Comment: Its exactly as the error says, in SQL Server you can't select a column unless its also grouped by OR aggregated.

Comment: There isn't even a column `iis` in your SQL you've shown us...

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: You are grouping by `ARTICLE_INCARNATION.article_incarnation_id`, but you have given your table an alias of `AIN` therefore you should be grouping by `AIN.article_incarnation_id`. I also suspect that the query you have posted is not the same query that threw the error in the title, the query in the question would probably throw the error `The multi-part identifier "ARTICLE_INCARNATION.article_incarnation_id" could not be bound.`.

Comment: This was the answer, thank you so much. I see that it was a stupid mistake now.

Answer (score 1):

You have same table name but `schema`s are different that cause the problem. :

```
ARTICLE_INCARNATION.article_incarnation_id
```

AND

```
[dbo].[ARTICLE_INCARNATION]
```

Choose which one you want to aggregate or display. If you want both then define proper alias.